# Unable to understand the exception in Prod, while the same functionality works in Dev mode

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "" at /var/www/<projectId>/src/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/FeatureToggleBundle/EventListener/RequestListener.php line 33
```

And the trace as follows

```
    {/var/www/<projectId>/src/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/FeatureToggleBundle/EventListener/RequestListener.php:33 {▼
    Oro\Bundle\FeatureToggleBundle\EventListener\RequestListener->onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) …
    › if ($event->isMasterRequest()) {
    ›     throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    › }
  }
  /var/www/<projectId>/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:126 {}
```

And the request for offer functionality, works perfectly fine in Dev but not in Prod.

I have ensured that the files are updated and also made sure there is nothing that is amiss.

Checked DB migrations and ensured that all changes are intact

The fact that the functionality works fine on Dev is strange and When I do <App_URL>/index_dev.php/customer/request/create on the 500 Internal error does not show any error but infact loads the RFQ page perfectly fine and intact.

Any suggestions to debug this error or an understanding of What may be going wrong ?

Comment: is prod environment on the same system?If so, did you removed/cleared all cache files when switching to prod?

Comment: Hey John, I have done cache:clear for both Dev and Prod and yes, It is on the same system.

Comment: have you tried using rm -rf var/cache/* ?

Comment: Yes @singebatteur I have.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message and the stack trace, you have the feature enabled in dev but disabled in a prod environment. Usually, it happens because of the cache.

1. So the first suggestion is to remove the file cache manually, using `rm -rf var/cache/*`, and if you are using Redis, flush the redis database as well. The cache:clear command is not always reliable.
2. You say that the exception is thrown only in prod, but the error stack-trace has wrappers, that must be used only with the `debug=true` option in the AppKernel. Please, make sure, you haven't customized the index.php file to enable debug, as it is unsecure, and make sure your web-server virtual host is configured to use index.php, not index_dev.php.
3. The exception comes from the feature toggle bundle. As the last resort, you can check [the documentation](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/feature-toggle/), on how the feature is implemented, and debug the listener from the trace (src/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/FeatureToggleBundle/EventListener/RequestListener), to see, where the value comes from.